# Using data annotations for optional fields

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have a field that's optional, but if it's there it must be exactly six characters long.

The StringLength Dataannotation doesn't seem to allow for this.  Is there some way of combining things to get what I want?  I could theoretically use Regular Expressions, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is extremely vague. Seems to me it's as simple as checking the length of the input if it's 6 then set the field equal to the input else set the field to null...

Comment: This is specifically to do with DataAnnotation validation.  That's what I'm trying to use to do the length-checking.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 6)]
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

With this you're specifying a Maximum of 6 chars and a Minimum of 6 chars. If you enter something below 6, you'll get a message like this one when trying to post the data:

> ```
> The field MyString must be a string with a minimum length of 6 and a
> maximum length of 6.
> ```

**OR** a Regular Expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{6,6}$")]
public string MyString { get; set; }
```

---

There's a way around this by implementing the [IValidatableObject](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) interface, but you'll lose the client side/unobtrusive validation. The validation will be done on the server side:

```
public class MyClass : IValidatableObject
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    // ... Other fields ...

    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
                                                 ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString))
        {
            if(MyString.Length != 6)
            {
                // ... Validation rules ...
                yield return new ValidationResult("MyString must be 6 chars long",
                                                   new[] { "MyString" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok - but I only want to check that the length is correct _if_ they've entered anything at all.  If they've left it blank then that's also fine.

Comment: Uhmmm... I see. I don't know about anything in the box with unobtrusive validation built-in... but you could try this: [RequiredIfNotEmpty] from this OS project: http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: Some great ones there, thanks!
I've currently resorted to: 
[RegularExpression("([A-Z]{3})|^$", ErrorMessage = "Must be three letters long, or blank")]
Which is ugly, but works.